# "Check update" is not working in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have tried to "check update" in android studio

```
Help>Check for Updates
```

but it says

```
Connection failed. Please check your network connection and try again
```

But my Internet is working fine. .I've also tried to switch off my firewall. Is this bug of google service?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update : Whenever updates | installations are failed, start the android studio as **administrator**.

Old Answer:
This is possibly a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55336) of Android Studio.

The following steps may help to fix this issue:

1. Open configuration
2. Select Settings
3. Select HTTP Proxy
4. Set to use no proxy
5. Restart Andriod studio

Comment: - Open configuration
- Select Settings
- Select HTTP Proxy
- Set to use no proxy
- Restart Andriod studio

Comment: Your comment should be an answer

Comment: In Android Studio 1.1, open configuration is select menu File/Settings, then select HTTP Proxy and so on.

Comment: Thanks, you really saved my day.

Comment: where is "configuration"? I don't find it anywhere in 2.0

Comment: @ShirishHerwade on my Mac its called "Preferences...", the settings... or press CTRL+,

Comment: Still i m getting issue. can any one help me regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

**start the android studio as administrator.** that helps me in android studio whenever updates/installations are failed.

Comment: Now, in september 2018, this still happens... and this answer solved the issue, not the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Maybe u can try: Settings -> System settings -> HTTP Proxy -> auto-detect proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. To fix I had to manually download a newer version from https://developer.android.com/studio/.

I'm currently running **Android Studio 3.2.1** and it updates fine.

Also, in **Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy** make sure that **Auto-detect proxy settings** is checked.

[Check Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYeat.png)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a bug. I can confirm that the update worked perfectly fine on my home network. When on my office network, trying to update gives a connection error.

Must have something to do with the firewall...or some service that's not Checked to handle connections based on `domain/home/public` policies.

Answer (score 0):

I tried no proxy option at both office and home network.

At home, "Check Update" works fine, but getting the error you mentioned with office network.

To avoid this error, you need to provide the proxy details from your office IT administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an also problem for VPN connected users. Try to disconnect and check for updates it will work. It worked for me